# How do I load/parse a SceneKit .scn file into my Metal app?

Tags: scenekit, metal, modelio, metalkit

I want to create a 3D scene with the `SceneKit` modeler and then read it into my `Metal` app. I see there is `SceneKit` and `ModelIO` API to do this but I am unclear on how the pieces fit together.

So, what I need is path from `.scn` file -> `MDL Mesh` -> geometry + texture. I am unclear on how I would sync my `Metal` shaders with materials created in the `SceneKit` modeler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two main parts to what you're asking here: getting SceneKit data into ModelIO, and rendering ModelIO data with Metal.

1. To get SceneKit scenes into ModelIO, first use SceneKit API (`SCNScene` or `SCNSceneSource` to load the `.scn` file, then use ModelIO API to get the objects you want as meshes. You can create a `MDLAsset` from the entire scene using [`assetWithSCNScene:bufferAllocator:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlasset/1643661-assetwithscnscene?language=objc) and then walk through the asset's object hierarchy in ModelIO to find the mesh you want, or walk through the node hierarchy in SceneKit to find the `SCNNode` or `SCNGeometry` you want and then get the mesh to ModelIO using [`objectWithSCNNode:bufferAllocator:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlobject/1643660-init) or [`meshWithSCNGeometry:bufferAllocator:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlmesh/1643663-init).
2. As for using ModelIO meshes in a Metal app, Apple has a [sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/MetalKitEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016233) that shows how to use ModelIO to load an OBJ mesh, use MetalKit to get the mesh data into Metal GPU buffers, and hook up the material information you get from ModelIO to shader variables for use in your own renderer.

You should be able to put the two of these together: where the sample code loads an OBJ to get a `MDLAsset` or `MDLMesh`, use the methods in (1) to get an asset or mesh out of a SceneKit file instead.

The SceneKit material model is of course much more complicated than the simple Phong shader used in the sample code. But the sample code does show how to iterate through a `MDLMaterial`'s properties and set corresponding arguments in a Metal shader — if you create a more complicated shader, just follow the same steps to map the material properties to whatever your shader's inputs are.

Comment: Ah hah! So - in a nutshell - I give geometry and materials names in the modeler: "my box", "cool material" and then retrieve the geometry/material during the traversal - via either SceneKit or ModelIO traversal methods. The key is to label things. Have I got that right?

Comment: You can iterate materials regardless of whether they're labeled, but labels certainly can help you keep track.

Comment: Wait, what? How do I identify an item in the scene without a label. Two textured spheres implies four (4) labels (assuming distinct material descriptions) no?

Comment: Although assetWithSCNScene:bufferAllocator: is documented - https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlasset?language=objc - it is not actually available to use. Typing in the method call in code shows the method is not available. Sigh ...

Comment: You need to `import SceneKit.ModelIO` or `#import <SceneKit/ModelIO.h>` to get the SCN/MDL bridging bits.